# nested quotes situation in mvc view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC project in view I am trying to get data with code below. My problem is a syntax error

```
@functions{

            string GetRootRowHtml(List<CORE.Models.Category> categories, int parentId)
            {
                string html = String.Empty;
                foreach (var category in categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId))
                {
                    var childList = GetRootRowHtml(categories, category.Id);
                    var categoryHtml = "<li class=\"dd-item\" data-id=\"" + category.Id + "\" data-role=\"collapsible\" data-iconpos=\"left\" data-inset=\"false\">";
                    categoryHtml += "<div class=\"dd-handle dd-nodrag\">";
                    categoryHtml += "<div style=\"margin: 0 10px; width:25px; height:25px; float: left;\"></div>";
                    categoryHtml += "<span class=\"label label-info\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrows\" ></i></span>" + category.Name.Replace("'", @"\'") +
                                    "</div>" +
                                    "<span class=\"pull-right menu_process\">";
                    if (CORE.Models.User.IsAllowedTo(CORE.Models.User.AccessType.CATEGORY_UPDATE))
                    {
                        categoryHtml += "<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-circle\" onClick=\"UpdateCategory(" + category.Id + ")\" style =\"margin-right:10px;\" type=\"button\" title =\"" + Resources.Resource.Edit + "\"> <i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i></button>";
                        categoryHtml += "<button class=\"btn btn-success btn-circle\" onClick=\"ShowCategory(" + category.Id + ",\""+ category.Name + "\")\" style =\"margin-right:10px;\" type=\"button\" title =\"" + Resources.Resource.Edit + "\"> <i class=\"fa fa-list\"></i></button>";

                    }
                    html += categoryHtml;
                }
                return html;
            }

        }
```

Code above, I take an syntax error in code line below.

```
                categoryHtml += "<button class=\"btn btn-success btn-circle\" onClick=\"ShowCategory(" + category.Id + ",\""+ category.Name + "\")\" style =\"margin-right:10px;\" type=\"button\" title =\"" + Resources.Resource.Edit + "\"> <i class=\"fa fa-list\"></i></button>";
```

Error is below

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Reason for this  is quotes. In onclick method there is a quato and there is also another quato for string in onclick function parameter. I tried a lot but couldn't find solution.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is correction, due to double quote in category name argument, It 
terminate the function string in html.

You can put it in single quote.

```
ShowCategory(" + category.Id + ",'"+ category.Name + "')
```

So final code should look like below.

```
categoryHtml += "<button class=\"btn btn-success btn-circle\" onClick=\"ShowCategory(" + category.Id + ",'"+ category.Name + "')\" style =\"margin-right:10px;\" type=\"button\" title =\"" + Resources.Resource.Edit + "\"> <i class=\"fa fa-list\"></i></button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `single quotes` inside `double quotes`. It's much more easy to format.

```
categoryHtml += "<button class='btn btn-success btn-circle' onclick='ShowCategory(" + category.Id + ", '"+ category.Name + "')' style ='margin-right:10px;' type='button' title ='" + Resources.Resource.Edit + '"> <i class='fa fa-list'></i></button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to answer your question really, but there are much better and cleaner techniques to solve this. It's really hard to maintain code like this, and it's too easy to run into errors. Your code with all the quote escapes is a big mess. You should see how clean this would work using "Display Templates", "Helper Methods" or other template techniques, even `string.Format()` and "string interpolation" (C# 6+) do a better job.

I'd strongly recommend to rewrite to use a helper Method.
You could write your Html just like this:

```
@helper WriteRootRowHtml(List<CORE.Models.Category> categories, int parentId) {
    foreach (var category in categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId))
    {
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="@category.Id" data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="left" data-inset="false">
        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag">
        <div style="margin: 0 10px; width:25px; height:25px; float: left;"></div>
        <span class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-arrows" ></i></span> @(category.Name.Replace("'", @"\'"))
        </div>
        <span class="pull-right menu_process">

        @if (CORE.Models.User.IsAllowedTo(CORE.Models.User.AccessType.CATEGORY_UPDATE))
        {
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" onClick="UpdateCategory(@(category.Id))" style ="margin-right:10px;" type="button" title="@Resources.Resource.Edit">
              <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle" onClick="ShowCategory(@(category.Id), '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(category.Name)')" style ="margin-right:10px;"  type="button" title="@Resources.Resource.Edit">
              <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
            </button>
        }
    }
}
```

You see, no quote escaping, you can simply interpolate the Html with variables in Razor syntax. Use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` if your name could contain some special characters (like quotes inside text) to prevent breaking your Html output.

The helper `WriteRootRowHtml` can be executed directly using `@WriteRootRowHtml(...)` within View, and it will output to view, but if you only want the string for further processing, you can do:

```
@{
    var generatedHtml = WriteRootRowHtml(...).ToHtmlString();
}
```